# PHP - php.ini file changes are not recognized

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, configuration-files, digital-ocean

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- remote server on digitalocean

I've set the sendmail_path directive in the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file to:

```
"/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/.msmtp_php --logfile /var/log/msmtp.log -a gmail -t"
```

However, when I check my `phpinfo()` file, it still states sendmail_path's local value is: `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

I've already restarted my web server and the results are the same.
Loaded Configuration File is states the file loaded is: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

To determine if this is the file that's actually being loaded, I've also tried renaming the php.ini file to php.ini.old, and also renamed the conf.d to conf.d.old. However, after restarting the server, the `phpinfo()` page still states my Loaded Configuration File is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

At this point, I'm assuming my web server is loading some other php.ini file. However, from where???

Do you guys have any suggestions on what I can further do? I'm at a loss here :(

Comment: have you checked the error log? Maybe there is an error in your php.ini file, so then it just loads the default values

Comment: Apparently I did not remove the ; before sendmail_path. I'm guessing the semicolon comments the line. So embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the php.ini file path with phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
Did you restart your web server ?

Are you using php-fpm (php5-fpm) so then you have to restart php-fpm also...